# How to make minimum_should_match work with nested mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue regarding ElasticSearch and More like this query.

Having mapping:

```
{
  "directory.v1": {
    "mappings": {
      "profile.event": {
        "properties": {
          "event": {
            "properties": {
              "naics": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "type": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "user_id": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and document (A) as a source and document (B) to be found with more like this query (for A)

Profile A (used as source):

```
{
  "_index": "directory.v1",
  "_type": "profile.event",
  "_id": "83731111.559",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "user_id": 8373,
    "event": {
      "naics": [
        {
          "value": 331,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 74,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 938,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2048,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 939,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2049,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 940,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2050,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 941,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2051,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 942,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2052,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 943,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2053,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 944,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2054,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 945,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2055,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 473,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 128,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 10,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 1242,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 472,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 1241,
          "type": "naics"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Profile B:

```
{
  "_index": "directory.v1",
  "_type": "profile.event",
  "_id": "46124111.559",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "user_id": 46124,
    "event": {
      "naics": [
        {
          "value": 331,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 74,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 938,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2048,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 939,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2049,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 940,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2050,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 941,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2051,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 942,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2052,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 943,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2053,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 944,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2054,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 945,
          "type": "naics"
        },
        {
          "value": 2055,
          "type": "naics"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

where B doc has all elements (naics) included in A document.

So that I really do not understand why for query:

```
   {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "event.naics",
          "query": {
            "more_like_this": {
              "like": [
                {
                  "_id": "83731111.559",
                  "_type": "profile.event"
                }
              ],
              "fields": [
                "event.naics.value"
              ],
              "min_term_freq": 1,
              "min_doc_freq": 1,
              "minimum_should_match": "8%"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**I have results!!**

but when I increase min_should_match >= 9% it does not match at all and I get no results.

Also tried to do something like this which gets me some results up to 11%

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "event.naics",
      "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
          "like": [
            {
              "_id": "83731111.559",
              "_type": "profile.event"
            }
          ],
          "fields": [
            "event.naics.*"
          ],
          "min_term_freq": 1,
          "min_doc_freq": 1,
          "minimum_should_match": "11%"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And termvecor for source document is:

```
{
    "_index": "directory.v1",
    "_type": "profile.event",
    "_id": "83731111.559",
    "_version": 5,
    "found": true,
    "took": 0,
    "term_vectors": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get the term vector for document "A" for field event.naics.value you will see you have 24 terms in total each with term frequency 1.
So when you do 8% match that will be rounded down to 1 clause of the 24 generated should clauses, so you get a match. But 9% of 24 will round to 2 clauses should match which is no bueno as each of your nested document has only one value.

For calculation details you can see the bottom of this page
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/99f88f15c5febbca2d13b5b5fda27b844153bf1a/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/lucene/search/Queries.java

And morelikethis source is here
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/46a79127edfb0cc93b7580624010ff81ca0cb2f4/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/lucene/search/MoreLikeThisQuery.java

Term vector

```
POST /directory.v1/profile.event/83731111.559/_termvectors
{
  "fields":["event.naics.value"],
  "offsets" : false,
  "payloads" : false,
  "positions" : false,
  "term_statistics" : true,
  "field_statistics" : true
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I see now that calculation is made on a leaf. What I'm trying to achieve is actually check occurrences for same naics between document (% should match number or objects/naics in other document) Can I achieve that with such nested structure or should I go with array or something?  But still don't get why should match is calulated on array of items (24) and then it is checking leaf occurence (.value) ?

Comment: If you do not map it as a nested type it will be flattened, maybe that is what you need for your use case. But be aware that in this case the  relation between event.naics.value and event.naics.type will be lost. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: yea, that's why I dont want to change mapping. But still I dont get it, how did you count event.naics[] = 24, and then calculated that event.naics.value has single clause, isn't that event.naics has 16 same clauses?

Comment: See edit above for how to get terms in a field. event.naics for the document A you posted has 24 objects in the array (may be your document is wrong then?)

Comment: added edit in my post; termvector definition - which is none :/ I've also tried to use event.naics.* instead of event.naics.value there are 'some' results.

Comment: you can try "fields": ["*"] for all the fields but not sure what your problem is. What version of Elasticsearch are you using and what tool are you using for querying?

Comment: elasticsearch-head and ES 5.1.1, using "*" did give me some results but still I can't reach minimum_should_match about 50% even though my documents have almost 75% (24/18) of common naics entries...